# How to configure .htaccess file for rewrite rules to get rid of extensions, trailing slashes, www?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, trailing-slash

This is what I want -

When somebody enters site.com/page.php or site.com/page or site.com/page/ , all should work the same, and the url displayed in the address bar should be site.com/page [ I don't like extensions and trailing slashes ]

I also want to get rid of the www from the url bar, as it's unnecessary.

This is my current .htaccess files Rewrite rules -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=permanent,L] 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This solves the www and the extension issue, but not the trailing slash one!

But, more importantly, I recently installed WordPress at site.com/blog, but whenever I try to access that, I am redirected to the 404 page instead. It works when I remove all the Rewrites!

Have I messed up my rewrites? I am not a regular expressions ninja!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the top of your existing .htaccess file, above any existing rules e.g. Wordpress rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if the host is not site.com, e.g www.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site\.com$ [NC]
#then redirect to site.com e.g to remove the www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

#if the URL ends with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
#redirect to URL without slash
RewriteRule . http://site.com/%1 [R=301,L] 

#skip wordpress site which starts with blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich. I edited to ignore /blog in every rule to make it work! Was resulting in a 'Too many redirects' otherwise.
Now I have everything in place! :)