# how to specify only one directory for an .htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i had a rewrite rule working fine where any pages in the format `site.com/dir/page1.php` were translated into the format `site.com/page1`.  i achieved that with:

```
# 1. turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On

# 2. remove the www prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# 3.  send all non-secure pages to secure pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# 4. if 404 not found error, go to homepage
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# 5. if url received with trailing slash (e.g. http://domain/test/) then go to correct page (e.g. http://domain/pages/test.php)
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ includes/$1.php

# 6. if url received WITHOUT trailing slash (e.g. http://domain/test) then go to correct page (e.g. http://domain/pages/test.php)
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ includes/$1.php
```

i have now set up a blog at `site.com/blog/` and when i try and visit the blog it is displaying the home page (ie a 404 error).

i *think* the error is at part #5 and #6 and that somehow i need to specify that the rewrite rule is specifically only for the 'includes' directory?  but i could be wrong, any help appreciated, thank you!

**update:**

i tried the solution to ignore the 'blog' directory here:

[How to configure .htaccess file for rewrite rules to get rid of extensions, trailing slashes, www?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525174/how-to-configure-htaccess-file-for-rewrite-rules-to-get-rid-of-extensions-trai?rq=1)

```
#skip wordpress site which starts with blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but that didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Please post a sample of the blog URL. Should there be any rewriting taking place in `blog/`?

Comment: thank you for your reply, it is a wordpress blog and i am just trying to access the blog 'as normal/out of the box' ie site.com/blog, so in my understanding i just need something that says leave all /blog links alone (this would include /blog/wp-admin etc too).  thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent rewriting on the `blog/`, place the following before your rules 5,6 (which are generi rewrites):

```
# Do not apply the following to the blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog

# 5. if url received with trailing slash (e.g. http://domain/test/) then go to correct page (e.g. http://domain/pages/test.php)
# Merged 5 & 6 together by making the trailing slash optional /?
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ includes/$1.php
```

Another possibility is to prevent rewriting on any directory that exists:

```
# Do not apply the following to actual existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Merged 5 & 6 together by making the trailing slash optional /?
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ includes/$1.php
```

Comment: thank you very much, that first code combination example is working - thank you!